# How decorate a export componenet using reduxForm if withStyles HOC is being called togeteher?

Tags: react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

I want decorate my component with reduxForm, but the function withStyles is being called. How can I decorate?

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({summary: state.dashboard.summary})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({dashboardList}, dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);

export default withStyles(dashboardStyle)(Dashboard);(Here!! How can i do it???)
```